# Firestore daily quota

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I developed a sample application using **Angular** and **Firestore**.
I deployed my application about 2 months ago and since then always has worked great.

In the last week, however, I noticed that the application is blocked after a couple of hours of usage for "client offline" error.
I found out that after 2 hours of usage I exceed the daily quota of reading operations.

The limit is 0,05 **milions** operations.
But normally I make 30-40 operations in a hour and I never got error before the last days.

Is something changed?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, i guess there is bug in their system or they changes something and never announced it. I have the same problem with my test app. After a few calls (20-30) i  get the same error. On thing to be sure, the problem is not from the angular. ;)

Comment: I just ran a few of my scripts and don't immediately run into problems. Are you sure you aren't reading collections that have grown over time?

Comment: These types of questions are better sent to the mail list on Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-firestore-discuss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After this question was asked on Google Groups, a user called [Michael Lehenbauer replied](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/quota%7Csort:date/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/PzlZ47NJU7Y/9vhat9AqBAAJ) with the following:

> Be aware that billing is based on document reads and so if you do a query with many results, each document counts as a read.

So unless you limit the reads performed, all documents in the collection or a parent document are read which can lead to many requests once your database grows (Which would explain why the app worked before).

A possible workaround to do this would be to cache the data somewhere locally and refresh it after some time or to add a limit clause to your requests.